# Field type for selecting a section (channel / structure / single)?

Tags: field, fieldtypes

I have a channel for products but in some cases I would like to associate a product with a structure containing documentation and release note pages:

```
http://mysite.com/product/my-product/docs/getting-started
                          ^--------^      ^-------------^
                              |                  |
                           channel             topic (from 'myProductStructure')
```

Is there an existing field type (or plugin) which would allow selection of the associated structure type:

```
Title: My Product  [text]
Doc Source: My Product Structure  [drop-down]
```

Such that I could use that in templates?

```
{% for entry in craft.entries.section( product.docSource ).slug( craft.request.lastSegment ) %}
    ...
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this with [LJ DynamicFields](https://github.com/lewisjenkins/craft-lj-dynamicfields/). In the plugin docs is an example of how to create a dropdown that is a list of all sections.